Permission Denied while sending RCS message to Test User
I am looking for a method by which I could send an RCS (Rich communication service) on test devices using the CURL from my systems, while i am using a test device to achieve the same, below are the steps which i am following and are giving me an error code 403 (PERMISSION_DENIED).

Registering as pattern on https://business-communications.cloud.google.com/console/partner-console

Creating my agent with agent ID : RCS-AGENT-ID, and region REGION.

Creating a testing device request for my mobile number 10-DIGIT-MOBILE-NUMBER-WITH-COUNTRY-CODE, which was then approved from the mobile phone

Generating a service account key by following navigation : settings > Service account > Create Key.

Using the downloaded json to try hit the curl to send test RCS:


curl -X POST "https://<<REGION>>-rcsbusinessmessaging.googleapis.com/v1/phones/<<MOBILE-WITH-COUNTRY-CODE>>/agentMessages?messageId='acd1'&agentId='<<RCS-AGENT-ID>>'" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "User-Agent: curl/rcs-business-messaging" \
-H "`oauth2l header --json service-account-key.json rcsbusinessmessaging`" \
-d "{
  'contentMessage': {
    'text': 'Hello, world!'
  }
}"


Following was the output i received
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "There was an error looking up the RBM agent (ID: '<<RCS-AGENT-ID>>') that corresponds to the Google Cloud Platform (GCP) project you're authenticating with.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}


This is becoming a blocker for my RCS integration

Hi - could you please remove the "rcs" tag from your question?  RCS is meant to be used for "Revision Control System".  Thanks, Pete

Hi - the mentioned has been done! Thanks!
